# Read the actual status of the piFace relay

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I fiddling around with Raspberry Pi + piFace Interface and Python. I can read the inputs and set the leds and relays. What I could not find is how I can determine the actual status of the Relays at a later stage. I use the pifacedigitalio python library.

Can somebody tell me how to read the status of the relays?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
import pifacedigitalio
piface = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital()
print(piface.relays[0].value)
```

http://pifacedigitalio.readthedocs.io/example.html